# Проблема кодировки и отображения содержимого при парсинге(питон)

Tags: python, парсер, visual-studio-2015, кодировка

Люди добрые, подскажите, пожалуйста) я новичок, прошу камни в меня не кидать))
Хочу запарсить сайт, столкнулся одновременно с двумя проблемами, делаю по примеру как с ютуба

но получаю ошибку енкодинга и не могу понять работает метод prettify() или нет, но похоже что нет. При таком коде вот такая ошибка

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    import urllib.request
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import csv

    def get_html(url):
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        return response.read()

    def parse(html):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        div = soup.find('div', class_='col-md-8 col-left')
        print(div.prettify())

    def main():
        parse(get_html('сайт'))

     if __name__ == '__main__':
         main()
```

[image: Код Ошибки]

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    import urllib.request
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import csv

    def get_html(url):
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        return response.read()

    def parse(html):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        div = soup.find('div', class_='col-md-8 col-left', encoding='utf-8')
        print(div.prettify())

    def main():
        parse(get_html('тот же'))

     if __name__ == '__main__':
         main()
```

тогда выдает ошибку такую уже:
[image: Ошибка pretiffy]

Собственно вопрос, добавив енкодинг на 17 строке, я исправил ошибку кодировки?
И если да, тогда вопрос второй почему метод prettify() не работает?
Делал без этого метода просто в maine писал print(parse(get_html('ссылка на сайт'))) и в ответ программа выдавала None
Вопрос где я нагрешил?)) Извините, что вопрос наверное глупый, но все же)) Спасибо!)

Comment: Объект div.prettify не имеет атрибута prettify. посмотри что содержит div

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, первый код работает на другом компьютере, все четко получается, это проблема с кодировкой именно в моей системи или в студии...не знаете кодировку правильно прописать и куда?

Comment: И я так понимаю, что мой код почему-то использует кодировку cp866, хотя должен использоват ютф-8

Comment: поставь точку остановки и сравни данные перед выходом

Comment: Не понял( куда точку поставить?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/5557y8b4.aspx

Comment: Похоже нашел решение проще)) вынес в ответ) спасибо, что откликнулись)

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен, точнее сказать, обошел я его.
Переустановил питон, снес студию, поставил пачарм. все работает

Видно при установке прошлый раз питона, съехали кодировки. Это не точно. Но банальная переустановка языка и смена IDE помогла.